# GridGain transactions issues

Tags: gridgain

In our project we are testing how transactions work in distributed environment. As a part of the project we are testing opensource edition of GridGain 6.5.5.

We have faced lots of problems **in the following testcase:**

1. We are testing a cache without any additional rules.
2. The cache stores an id-String as a key and BigDecimal as a value.
3. We are testing base operations (addition and subtraction) on values of the first cache from 6, 12 and 18 clients. One operation looks like "subtract X from A, add X to B".
4. GridGain application is deployed as a .war file in WildFly.
5. Clients are connecting to WildFly with deployed GridGain using HTTP and send a list of operations to do (we are testing batches with 1 operation, 50, 500, 1000, 5000 operations).
6. We are testing clustered multinode mode with transactions, configuration files that we have used are attached further.
7. We have tested both pessimistic and optimistic transactions separately.
8. We call result values "consistent" if they are equal to the dummy-mode: one client, batch=1, one node. We have a dummy program for cross-check (its results in this mode is always equal to GridGain in local mode).

**The issues are:**

1. If we are doing transaction as-is (subtract from one keys value, add to another) we face two problems: deadlocks and inconsistency if we get no deadlocks. The number of inconsistent values is small but we can't avoid it -- it's about 12 per 1000 key-values.
2. If we transform our requests to be sorted by key in each client (so the order of operation may change) we can avoid deadlocks and inconsistency. But we get another issues: if the batch is at least 500, we have non-ending transaction failures. If the batch is small, we have GridGain failing completely (it doesn't respond to the current query).
3. Everything is working very slow and we have almost no CPU load at the same time (About 6 seconds for batch=1000 operations). Is it ok?

**Our hardware:**

8x Dell M620 blades, 256GB RAM, 2x8 core Xeon E2650v2, 10GbE network.

**Attaches:**

1. GridGain optimistic config: https://gist.github.com/al-indigo/a2824aa62a3af8b18932
2. GridGain pessimistic config: the same but with
3. GridGain log for second issue: https://gist.github.com/al-indigo/233058772418fba8d341

Answer (score 2):

I have looked at the logs and am seeing the following JVM parameters

```
-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

With high degree of probability you are running into long GC pauses, and that is the likely reason why you are getting lock timeout exceptions. With memory settings like this, JVM can go into GC pauses for as much as 5 minutes, during which the world is locked and nothing can be done. To confirm this, you can collect GC logs using the following JVM options:

```
-Xloggc:/opt/server/logs/gc.log \
-verbose:gc \
-XX:+PrintGC \
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps \
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

My recommendation is to allocate about 10GB maximum per JVM and start more JVM instances. You can also try using **off-heap memory** feature of GridGain and allocate large memory space outside of the main Java heap - http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Off-Heap+Memory. Also, please take a look at GC tuning parameters here: http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Performance+Tips#PerformanceTips-TuneGarbageCollection

Another big suggestion is that you should not do individual **get(...)** operations in your transaction, but do a one **getAll(...)** call instead:

```
try (GridCacheTx tx = balanceCache.txStart()) {

    /*
     * ==============================================
     * This while loop calls get(...) many times and acquires one lock at a time.
     * It should be replaced with one getAll(...) call.
     * ===============================================
     */
    while (changes.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal> ent = changes.next();

        BigDecimal oldBalance = balanceCache.get(ent.getKey());

        balanceCache.putx(ent.getKey(), oldBalance.add(ent.getValue()));
    }

    tx.commit();
} catch (GridException ex) {
     throw new Exception("transaction failed", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Moving from the comment)

In order to avoid deadlocks you need to make sure that you acquire locks in the same order. This must be done when working with transactions in any system of records, be that Oracle database or GridGain data grid.

As for the performance, it should be very fast. Most likely it is a matter of configuration. Can I ask you to provide a reproducible example? (you can use pastbin.com to share your code)

Comment: As soon as we noticed that deadlock resolution doesn't work, of course we started avoiding deadlocks in a manual way (as you say). Nethertheless in classical DBMS a bunch of algorithms is used: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock_provision . So we thought that it could be in GridGain too.


But that's not the main point.


The main points are failures on rather small amount of data processed (log is attached to original question) and the speed.

Here is the sample code we use (configs for gridgain are in the question too): https://gist.github.com/al-indigo/438559003a7821c9779e

Comment: Can you please add the test harness code as well? It is critical that we try to reproduce it in the same way as you.

Comment: I'm not sure we can because of NDA. In general we use Ansible and our own playbooks to deploy everything and to run the tests. Since the tests start, there is no impact of other software layers except GridGain and java client applications. I can send you (privately - please give me a link to your email) our intermediate result table to prove that everything works not so fast as expected.

Comment: But I do not see any problems to reproduce the problem. Our program uses resteasy for accepting queries (and the is no problems with it) and the batch-query is parsed and executed the with the code I attached to the previous message. There are no other layers of tools in the middle. The application is deployed in wildfly8 as .war file. The queries are just CSV wrapped in http package.

Comment: And I have already attached all the needed configs to bring everything up.

Comment: I wanted to say once more that *the main issue is not the speed* but the unpredictable failure of gridgain after ~300000 queries. As you can see from the log (3. in the original issue) there are only GridGain-specific stacktraces and no mentions about our program at all.